# pandas reindex multindex to higher frequency dates

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table of IDs and dates of quarterly data and i would like to reindex this to daily (weekdays).

Example table:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out a pythonic or pandas way to reindex to a higher frequency date range e.g. daily and forward fill any NaNs.

so far have tried:

```
df = pd.read_sql('select date, id, type, value from db_table' con=conn, index_col=['date', 'id', 'type'])
dates = pd.bdate_range(start, end)
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, df.index.get_level_values(1), df.index.get_level_values(2)]
new_df = df.reindex(new_idx)

#this just hangs
new_df = new_df.groupby(level=1).fillna(method='ffill')
```

to no avail. I either get a

`Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`

Or, if the dates are consistent between ids and types the individual dates are reproduced multiple times (which sounds like a bug?)

Ultimately I would just like to group the table by date, id and type and have a consistent date index across ids and types.

Is there a way to do this in pandas?

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do with `merge`

```
new_idx_frame=new_idx.to_frame()
new_idx_frame.columns=['date', 'id', 'type']
Yourdf=df.reset_index().merge(new_idx_frame,how='right',sort =True).groupby('id').ffill()# here I am using toy data 
Out[408]: 
   id  date  type     value
0   1     1     1       NaN
1   1     1     2       NaN
2   2     1     1  666666.0
3   2     1     2   99999.0
4   1     2     1      -1.0
5   1     2     1      -1.0
6   1     2     2      -1.0
7   2     2     1   99999.0
8   2     2     2   99999.0
```

---

Sample data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'date':[1,1,2,2],'id':[2,2,1,1],'type':[2,1,1,1],'value':[99999,666666,-1,-1]})
df=df.set_index(['date', 'id', 'type'])
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([[1,2], [1,2],[1,2]])
```

Comment: @coldspeed I have add the sample data I used :-)

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. I end up with a dataframe that repeats t1 on 2014-12-31 for id 8 a total of 23 times and so on for other types, dates etc. Maybe am constructing the new multindex wrong? where dates in the following is all business days within the min/max range of my original table   ```new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, df.index.get_level_values(1), df.index.get_level_values(2)])```

Answer (score 0):

Wen-Ben's answer is almost there - thank you for that. The only thing missing is grouping by ['id', 'type'] when doing the forward fill.

Further, when creating the new multindex in my use case should have unique values:

```
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([dates, df.index.get_level_values(1).unique(), df.index.get_level_values(2).unique()])
```